# Share complex object with another process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipc

I do have a complex data-object. What's the best way to share it with another python process?

Background:
To avoid the `GIL` I spawn a second process which does all the calculation. It logs to the main-process using `UDP`. This calculation process needs input data which is this complex object. So how I share it the most easiest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using now following:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_remote_runner, args=(context,))
process.start()
```

This passes `context`-object to the remote_runner. This indeed uses `pickle` internally to pass the object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered serializing it using pickle?

```
import pickle
fid = open(filename,'w')
fid.write(pickle.dumps(data))
fid.close()
```

then load it in the other process:

```
fid = open(filename,'r')
directData = fid.read()
data = pickle.loads(directData)
fid.close()
```

Something similar can be done with other formats
    import json
    fid = open('jsonOutput','w')
    fid.write(json.dumps(data))
    fid.close()

If you didn't want to transfer via files you could transfer over a network connection